Como puedo hacer que se inicie sesión automáticamente con un usuario mediante un script?
He creado una GPO dentro de un dominio que ejecuta un script de inicio de equipo (cuando se enciende el ordenador se ejecuta ese script).
Lo que hace este script es crear una tarea programada que hace que se reinicie el ordenador cada día a las 23:00 h.
Aquí está el código del script (es un script de PowerShell):
# Definimos la hora en que queremos que se reinicie el ordenador
$triggerTime = "23:00" # Formato 24 horas HH:MM
       
# Creamos un nuevo trigger que se ejecutará diariamente a la hora especificada
$trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Daily -At $triggerTime
    
    
Definimos la accion que queremos que realice la tarea, en este caso, reiniciar el ordenador
$action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "shutdown.exe" -Argument "/r"
    
    
Especifica las opciones para ejecutar la tarea tanto si el usuario inició sesión como si no
$principal = New-ScheduledTaskPrincipal -UserId "SYSTEM" -LogonType S4U -RunLevel Highest
    
    
Creamos la tarea programada con las opciones especificadas
Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName "Reinici" -Trigger $trigger -Action $action -Principal $principal -Description "Reinicia l'ordinador cada dia a les 23:00" -Settings (New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet -AllowStartIfOnBatteries -DontStopIfGoingOnBatteries -StartWhenAvailable)

Todo esto funciona perfectamente, en los ordenadores que les asigno la GPO, cuando los reinicio para aplicar las políticas, se crea la tarea y se reinician a las 23:00, y si ya tienen la tarea creada también funciona, pero necesito que en esos ordenadores, se inicie la sesión automáticamente con un usuario específico, pienso que también se puede hacer a partir de un script de PowerShell que se ejecute al iniciar el PC.
Si hace falta más información para saber más, no duden en preguntar, puede ser que me haya dejado alguna cosa básica que hay saber, soy un poco novato.
Agradecería mucho que me pudieran ayudar.

Cambiando estos valores en el registro activas el autologon ,lo puedes dejar como un script aparte o lo metes antes de reiniciar los pcs:
$DirectReg = "Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon"

Set-ItemProperty -Path "$DirectReg" -Name 'AUTOADMINLOGON' -Value '1'

Set-ItemProperty -Path "$DirectReg" -Name 'DEFAULTPASSWORD' -Value 'CONTRAUSU'

Set-ItemProperty -Path "$DirectReg" -Name 'DEFAULTUSERNAME' -Value 'cuentausu@pepe.com'

Start-sleep -Seconds 2

